# Arranging elements horizontally in a dash application

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I'm trying to develop a Dash application in python. I tried adding `style={'display': 'inline-block'}` to the html.Div() component, as well as to other components, but couldn't set the drop-down menus to align in one row.

The page looks as follows:

with the inline styling:
[image: with inline style]
Without the inline styling:
[image: without inline style]

The code in the question was given to me as a template that needs to be filled properly. The complex hierarchy was part of the template. My job is to add code as needed. I'm adding only the problematic part of the code (without the title and the graph elements that are seen in the images):

```
df = pd.read_csv("dash\Pricing Data.csv")
colors = {
'background': '#111111',
'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

boxplot_layout = (
    dbc.Container(
        [dbc.Row(
                [
                    dbc.Col(
                        [
                            dbc.Card(
                                [
                                    dbc.CardBody(
                                        [
                                            dbc.Row(
                                                [
                                                    dbc.Col(
                                                        html.Div(
                                                            dbc.Row(
                                                                [
                                                                    dbc.Col(
                                                                        [
                                                                            dcc.Dropdown(
                                                                                id="aggregate-dropdown",
                                                                                options=[
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "label": "Total",
                                                                                        "value": "sum",
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "label": "Average",
                                                                                        "value": "average",
                                                                                    },
                                                                                ],
                                                                                value="sum",
                                                                                style={
                                                                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                                                                    # 'color': colors['text']
                                                                                },
                                                                            )
                                                                        ],
                                                                    ),
                                                                    dbc.Col(
                                                                        [
                                                                            dcc.Dropdown(
                                                                                id="y-dropdown",
                                                                                options=[
                                                                                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                                                                                    for i in df.columns],
                                                                                style={
                                                                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                                                                },
                                                                                value='Age'
                                                                            )
                                                                        ],
                                                                    ),
                                                                    dbc.Col(
                                                                        [
                                                                            html.Label(
                                                                                "by",
                                                                                style={
                                                                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                                                                    # 'color': colors['text']
                                                                                }
                                                                            )
                                                                        ],
                                                                    ),
                                                                    dbc.Col(
                                                                        [
                                                                            dcc.Dropdown(
                                                                                id="x-dropdown",
                                                                                options=[
                                                                                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                                                                                    for i in df.columns],
                                                                                style={
                                                                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                                                                    'padding': '3px ',
                                                                                },
                                                                                value='Age'
                                                                            )],),],)))],),])],inverse=True,)])])]))


app.layout = boxplot_layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Also, as can be seen in the images, there's an error message. I couldn't find solutions for this error, so if you have any ideas regarding its cause or how to find it I'll be grateful if you could post it too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did eventually was to change the style inside the Column components of the Drop-down menus, as well as the style of the Drop-down themselves. I used the tags 'padding' and 'width' and changed their values until it looked OK. I also used the value 'inline-block' for the 'display' tag.

For instance, here's the code for one of the drop-down menus and it's column:

```
dbc.Col(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="y-axis-dropdown",
            options=
            [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.columns],
            value='Age',
            style={'textAlign': 'center'}
        )
    ], style={
             'display': 'inline-block',
             'width': '25%',
             'padding': 30,
             'textAlign': 'center'
       }

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the doc [example](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/):

```
dbc.Row(
        [
            dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
            dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
            dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
        ]
    ),
```

it results something you are chasing for. So, that's the basic structure, removing unnecessary code, follows:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv()
colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id="aggregate-dropdown",
                        options=[
                            {
                                "label": "Total",
                                "value": "sum",
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Average",
                                "value": "average",
                            },
                        ],
                        value="sum",
                        style={
                            'textAlign': 'center',
                            # 'color': colors['text']
                        },
                    )
                ]), width=3
            ),
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id="y-dropdown",
                        options=[
                            {'label': i, 'value': i}
                            for i in df.columns],
                        style={
                            'textAlign': 'center',
                        },
                        value='Age'
                    )
                ]), width=3
            ),
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([
                    html.Label(
                        "by",
                        style={
                            'textAlign': 'center',
                            # 'color': colors['text']
                        }
                    )
                ]), width=1
            ),
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id="x-dropdown",
                        options=[
                            {'label': i, 'value': i}
                            for i in df.columns],
                        style={
                            'textAlign': 'center',
                        },
                        value='Age'
                    )
                ]), width=3
            ),
        ])
    ])
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Note I passed a 'width=' keyword argument to set the size of columns.

And that's the result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlFJi.png)

I hope it's that help you to find the better way to organize your code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to apply your solution. Did you simplify the hierarchy?

Comment: yep, removing the dbc.Cards and Cardbody stuffs